How do i shift the axis of a chart in plotly
I'm trying to make this ridgeplot chart in plotly and its mostly working ok, but for some reason the top trace is getting cut off and i can't figure out how to move the trace down a bit. I can do it manually by dragging the axis
the code i have
for i, time_unit in enumerate(time_units):
    fig = go.Figure()

    df_year = df[df['year'] == time_unit]
    months = sorted(df['month'].unique())
    for j, month in enumerate(months):
        df_month = df_year[df_year['month'] == month]
        fig.add_trace(go.Violin(
            x=df_month['metric_value'],
            name=calendar.month_name[month],
            side='negative',
            box_visible=False
        ))
    fig.update_layout(
        title=f'Ridge Plot for Year {time_unit}',
        xaxis_title='Metric Value',
        yaxis_title='Month',

        yaxis=dict(automargin=True, domain=[0.00, 0.00], autorange='reversed',),
        violingap=0,
        violingroupgap=0,
        violinmode='overlay',
        height=1200

    )
fig.show()


this is the goal


You can set the y-axis limits to your desired values with
fig.update_yaxes(
    range=(lower, upper),
    constrain='domain'
)


Just change the lower and upper to the values you want

You need to set the height to be a little bit larger. for example, if you want to set it to 500:
fig = px.violin(x=x,y=x)
fig.update_layout(height=500)
fig.show()

